# Why does Magento POST to its own /app/etc/local.xml?

Tags: security

It seems to be initiated at admin operations, such as catalog save/edit. As seen in the logs. The client IP for the POST is the server's internal IP.

```
302 2014-08-30T06:43:40+00:00 POST /index.php/admin/catalog_product/save/id/8830/key/ee3cb37b55e431ada508af992e88abbb/ HTTP/1.1 
403 2014-08-30T06:43:40+00:00 POST /app/etc/local.xml HTTP/1.1 
200 2014-08-30T06:48:39+00:00 GET /index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/8830/key/e5c6b7e5d662d8b4c39be5b31b761f28/ HTTP/1.1 
403 2014-08-30T06:48:39+00:00 POST /app/etc/local.xml HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah, found the answer in the release notes:

> Added verification of access level for app/etc/local.xml. 
>   * Now if server configuration has issue and this file accessible from browser admin user gets notification in backend.

Comment: Yep, sanity checking to make sure app/etc/local.xml is inaccessible to external sources.