# Getting “access forbidden by rule” error at magento in nginx server /app/etc/local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, error, security, nginx, server-setup

I am getting this error for my website which is built on magento-1.9.0.

```
2015/07/13 05:50:44 [error] 1371#0: *491517 access forbidden by rule, client: **.***.***.***, server: www.example.com, request: "POST /app/etc/local.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

For your information: the IP address is always my own server. This only happens whenever I try to edit or update any item of "Shopping Cart Price Rules". There was a magento bug of shopping cart price rule and I have used a extension which is mentioned here https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix . That extension works perfectly in my local environment however it is also not working in live. I guess this error is preventing that extension to work perfectly. My live server is running on nginx.

Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer to [Why does Magento POST to its own app/etc/local.xml?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34161/why-does-magento-post-to-its-own-app-etc-local-xml)

Comment: @fschmengler: Thanks for your help. Does this mean that I have to set permission via SSH for that file so that it's become inaccessible?

Comment: It's already the case ("access forbidden by rule"). Actually these messages are a good thing, Magento would warn you in the admin panel if it *could* access the file via HTTP

Comment: @fschmengler: However, it's not warning me in the admin panel, instead, it's giving me this message in the error log of nginx.

Comment: Yes and that means, everything is fine. Magento tries to access app/etc/local.xml via HTTP which fails, so you get this error log. And the point is, that it should fail! Otherwise everybody could see your database credentials.

Comment: @fschmengler: Thanks a lot. You saved a lot of my time. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [Why does Magento POST to its own app/etc/local.xml?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34161/why-does-magento-post-to-its-own-app-etc-local-xml) might not have been clear enough, I'll add this as an answer:

Actually these messages are a good thing, Magento would warn you in the admin panel if it *could* access the file via HTTP. If you see this log message, everything is fine. Magento tries to access `app/etc/local.xml` via HTTP, which fails, so you get this error log. And the point is, that it should fail! Otherwise everybody could see your database credentials, by accessing `http://example.com/app/etc/local` in the browser.

However, if these log messages annoy you and you are confident that
your server setup will stay as secure as it is, you can easily remove
this feature:

> #### Getting rid of the security notification
>
> To get rid of this security check, do not attempt to hack the Magento
>   core (as some forum threads have suggested in the past). Instead, you
>   can just modify the admin-theme to remove this check. Open up the
>   following file or create it if it does not exist:
>
> ```
> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml
> ```
>
> Then add the following code to it:
>
> ```
> <layout>
>     <default>
>         <remove name="notification_security" />
>         <remove name="notification_survey" />
>     </default>
> </layout>
> ```
>
> This removes the blocks notification_security and notification_survey
>   from the backend-pages entirely, skipping therefor the security check.
>   No core hacks involved.

<sup>**Source:** http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/1322-client-denied-by-server-configuration-appetclocalxml</sup>

Remember to clean the layout cache afterwards.