# Save error only in System/Config

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, nginx

Please note I have tried the reference post that is a possible duplicate. The error only happens in System config when I try to save a new Product Placeholder

I am getting the following error when trying to save a product place holder. I am able to save product images without an issue.

```
2015/10/01 12:48:58 [crit] 10749#0: *2 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 76.xxx.xxx.221, server: www.damin.us, request: "POST /index.php/someadmin/system_config/save/section/catalog/key/fb1b1054099c511522a4e2eb696cd55a/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.us", referrer: "http://www.domain.us/index.php/someadmin/system_config/edit/section/catalog/key/03a8b3dd274e9c375fa768d3f920fba0/"
2015/10/01 12:50:39 [error] 10749#0: *29 access forbidden by rule, client: 54.xxx.xxx.235, server: www.domain.us, request: "POST /app/etc/local.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.us"
```

I have tried this without success
[Getting “access forbidden by rule” error at magento in nginx server /app/etc/local.xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74146/getting-access-forbidden-by-rule-error-at-magento-in-nginx-server-app-etc-loc?noredirect=1#comment98149_74146)

**UPDATES:**

I have set my permissions on the entire site to 644 and 755 with my var, media and app/etc to set to o+w. Problem still is happening.

Comment: @QaisarSatti I referenced that post in my post saying I Tried that and it did not work. Please read my entire post.

Comment: Do you use a custom admin theme?

Comment: No, standard theme

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually with the first part of the error in the log

```
*2 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body
```

The user assigned to that account was user:nginx, I switched the site to run on nginx:nginx and then re-chowned the folder ***/var/lib/nginx/tmp*** to ***nginx:nginx*** and it works.

The problem was that the main user did not have right to create the tmp file in that folder.